# ACF: Grid based on field value

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a “company pages” field group and a template that displays all of the companies in a grid. One of the fields in the “company pages” group is INDUSTRY.

I now want to to be able to sort that “ALL COMPANIES" page so it shows only the companies in a particular INDUSTRY.

I’d prefer using a dropdown on the “ALL COMPANIES" page itself to select the industry. Changing the dropdown would reload the page based on the selected industry. But another possibility is an "INDUSTRY" dropdown in the header menu.

I'm hoping that there is a way to do this by adding a parameter to the ALL COMPANIES url. As in "mysite.com/allcompanies/?industry=auto." Possible?

BTW, I posted to ACF's forum but p[osts are not being read there for some reason.

Comment: Have you done any work on this?  The stack is to help with code but we need to see what you've tried.

Comment: I have tried coding the template for the ALL COMPANIES page with "if (get_field('industry') == "Auto Technology") {SHOW AUTO CAMPANIES}" and that works. It would be kludgy to do it that way. Hoping there would be a way to do "mysite.com/allcompanies/?industry=auto" but not finding much.